# How can I return error from reject_if if not pass validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have three member, answer_set, answer which model_a don't have relation with model_c (it's don't have directly relation. the relation is looklike `member->answer_set->answer` ),so in the model_a i add this code for save attributes on associated records

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer_set, reject_if: :validation_method`

and add reject_if method for check validation of answer. from answer_set attributes

```
def validation_method(answer_sets_attribute)
  question = Question.find(answer_sets_attribute[:question_id])
  answer = answer_sets_attributes[:answers_attributes]
  return true if answer[:answer_text].blank? && answer[:answer_number].blank?
end
```

but when i return `true` from validation_method it's only except record which not passed but i want to return error and redirect to fill form again.

Comment: Don't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` if there is no relation.

Comment: I would recommend you add your actual models to the question instead. A lot of stuff goes lost in translation when you use really abstracted examples.

Comment: ok, I already changed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution to solved my problem.I used  `validates_presence_of :answer_set` and, it'll not pass the validation
when `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is rejected ,then it'll send the errors from validation and back to form.